# How can I play a specific sound from an Array?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, arkit

In my app, I’ve set the option to play, when the user tap a button, an audio description when an image is recognised, but I can’t select which file I want to play. My audio file are store in inside an array[image: Here’s my view w/ the play button]

Here’s the code that I use to play the single audio file:

```
func listenAudio(){

    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "afraid-of-destiny", withExtension: ".mp3") else { return }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

        guard let player = self.player else { return }

        player.play()

        self.audioButton.setTitle("Stop", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        self.player!.play()


    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

I thought to use an if/else, but it doesn’t work

Comment: What do you mean that your audio file is stored inside an array?

Comment: I mean that I saved the audio in this way, after importing that inside Xcode: “audio1”, “audio2”, “audio3”,

Answer (score 1):

If your audio files are an array of Strings do this:

```
func listenAudio(soundIndex: Int){
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: audioFileArray[soundIndex], withExtension: ".mp3") else { return }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now when I call self.audioButton.value(forKey: String) = actualImageInformation.audio Xcode gave me an error, saying Cannot invoke 'value' with an argument list of type '(forKey: String.Type)'

Comment: Could this be a different issue?  If not can you updated the code example above with your current code.